# How to integrate IMU9250 with RPLidar A1M8 using ROS 2 Humble

Tags: ros2, imu, rplidar

I am trying to integrate IMU9250 with RPLidar A1M8 using ROS 2 Humble. Therefore, I have taken the following steps:

1. Installed Ros2 humble on Raspberry Pi 4
2. Installed RPLidar A1M8
3. Launched the RPLidar to visualize the laser map on Rviz which I could see clearly

##### Question

How to integrate the IMU (MPU9250) with RPLidar to generate map using hector slam (not laser map).

Answer (score 0):

fuse the imu with your wheel encoder data using EKF to produce better odometry and then use the improved odometry and lidar to do mapping